# Merge in Oracle does not insert/update any rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, merge

Can you please suggest, what is wrong with this query? It is always extracting 0 records and not inserting the data.
I have checked the select query and it is returning the rows. But I am not sure what is wrong happening on the merge part that it does not insert/update the table.

```
ExtractType         NUMBER(9);
RecordsExtracted    NUMBER(9);
CurStatus           NUMBER(9);
StartDate           date;
ErrorMessage        NVARCHAR2(1000);
LastExtrctTimestamp DATE;
BEGIN
StartDate := sysdate;
ExtractType := 79;

-- Fetching the Last Extract Time Stamp 
Select  max(ExtractTimestamp) INTO LastExtrctTimestamp from ExtractRecords where Status = 2 and  ExtractRecords.ExtractType= ExtractType;

IF LastExtrctTimestamp IS NULL
THEN LastExtrctTimestamp := To_Date('01/01/1901', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
END IF;

MERGE INTO Table MCTH
USING (
    SELECT
            val1, val2, val3, .... val1
    FROM
            View_RPT
    WHERE TransitionDate >= LastExtrctTimestamp
) Core
ON(MCTH.valId= Core.ValId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
    MCTH.val1= Core.val1,
    MCTH.val2= Core.val2,
    MCTH.val3= Core.val3,
    .
    .
    MCTH.val4= Core.val4
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (MCTH.val1,MCTH.val2,MCTH.val3,MCTH.val4,
        ...,MCTH.val5)
VALUES (Core.val1,Core.val2,Core.val3,Core.val4,
        ...,Core.val5);
RecordsExtracted := SQL%RowCount;       

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('MCTH Records Merged:' || RecordsExtracted);

COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: The query returns data when it's run with `01/01/1901`, or the actual value of `max(ExtractTimestamp)`? Can you run the query within the block and output the rows to confirm it ought to be visible to the merge? Doesn't look likely to be the issue here but always worth checking... is all data committed in all sessions?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole .. The data has been checked and it's all coming out fine. The interesting part which I found today is, the above piece of code is returning "RecordsExtracte" with value in a Development database. But zero records in UAT/PRD environment. I tried GRANT MERGE permission, but that does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Roll your pl/sql logic into the merge statement, and you can test whether core is returning what you expect more easily:

```
merge into
  margincalltransitionhistory mcth
using (
  select
    margincalltransitionhistoryid,
    margincallid,
    fromworkflowstatename,
    toworkflowstatename, 
    transitiondate,
    transitionbyname,
    transitioncomment
  from
    margincalltranhistory_rpt
  where
    transitiondate >= (
      select  coalesce(max(extracttimestamp), date '1901-01-01')
      from    extractrecords
      where   status      = 2 and
              extracttype = 79)
  ) core
...
```

And for the love of God clean your code up -- I have no idea how you can work with that mess.

Comment: Thanks David, I will do that change you mentioned.